# Como iniciar um aplicação em Python junto com o Windows?(cx_freeze)

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Olá, estou tentando desenvolver um aplicação que se inicia junto com o windows, mas já tentei fazer com que o programa se auto copie para a pasta

> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup"

mas aparece acesso negado, eu estou utilizando Python 3.5 e o cx_freeze para gerar o executável.

Comment: Você pode compartilhar a parte do seu código usada para o programa se auto copiar?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer um bat e adiciona-lo junto ao startup do PC. Assim você faria com que seu bat tivesse o seguinte conteúdo:

```
C:/Caminho/Do/python.exe C:/Caminho/Do/Seu/Arquivo
```

E se você executar você pode executar seu script. Feito este arquivo bat, basta você adiciona-lo na lista de programas a inicializarem quando seu PC inicializar.

Comment: O problema é que eu não desejo apenas no meu computador, eu desejo através do cx_freeze conseguir fazer com que ele se inicie com o windows em qualquer máquina, Obj pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a pasta

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Não se esqueça de se certificar que está rodando seu programa como administrador.

Answer (score 0):

## Usar o próprio Python para isso

Você pode usar o próprio Python para escrever um arquivo `.bat` na pasta de inicialização de programas do Windows.

Você consegue acessar esta pasta seguindo as seguintes ordems:

- Pressione <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.
- Digite `shell:startup`
- Pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Vai iniciar seu `explorer`, e nele irá conter esta seguinte pasta:

> C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Criando um arquivo `.bat` nesta pasta, seu programa irá iniciar junto com Windows.

```py
from getpass import getuser
from os import path
from sys import argv

def startup(file_path=""):
        USER = getuser()
        if(file_path == ""):
            file_path = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
            bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER
        with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
            bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path + "\\" + argv[0])
startup()
```

O código cria um arquivo `.bat` na mesma pasta que citei acima.

Você também pode modificar este programa para iniciar arquivos `.exe`, como você mesmo citou ali acima, estava usando `cx_freeze`.

Você poderia automatizar isso para o próprio script criar um executável dele mesmo. Com o próprio modulo `cx_freeze`.

Se você souber utilizar o `cx_freeze`, dá para automatizar tudo. Como neste pequeno exemplo. Em outro script:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
  
setup(name = "startup" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      executables = [Executable("AQUI SEU ARQUIVO PRINCIPAL")])
```

Não sei o que você quer fazer com esse programa no startup do Windows. Porém se a intenção for ser silencioso, como em um malware. Você poderia automatizar tudo.

**Primeiro**, rode seu script de criar um executável. Depois você altera a linha:

```py
file_path = "DIRETORIO\\DO\\SEU\\SCRIPT\SCRIPT.EXE"
with open(bat_path + '\\' + "SEU_SCRIPT.EXE", "w+") as bat_file:
            bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
```